# Delete data from database using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to delete a particular record from the database.

My code is given below:

```
<%
String value = request.getParameter("Meter_No");
int v=Integer.parseInt(value);
try{

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDirver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;
user=shakir;password=shakir123");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("DELETE * FROM qesco_table 
  WHERE Meter_No ="+v+"");
rs.close();
conn.close();
  }catch(Exception e){
System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

But it is not deleting the data from database.

Can anyone guide me that where is the problem with the code?

Comment: Your connection string should be `jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433?databaseName=myDatabase&user=shakir&password=shakir123` Maybe that's not the only error. Please post your stacktrace.

Comment: `ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("DELETE * FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No ="+v);`

Comment: check wether ur connection to database is established, because query string seems to be ok.

Comment: Do never ever put database logic into your JSP! Your mixing presentation, business and even database logic in one file, ouch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing in your code is fine.

But You need to run your query using `st.executeUpdate()`.

So change the following line

```
ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery("DELETE * FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No ="+v+"");
```

to

```
st.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No ="+v);
```

**PLUS**

1. You don't need to have ResultSet in this program as your query is not going to return you any data to store.
2. You don't need to have empty "" (double quotes) at the end of your query.
3. You should close connection and others in `finally` block rather than try block itself.

And better if you try to use [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to write dynamic queries. So it will become something like,

```
<%
    String value = request.getParameter("Meter_No");
    int v=Integer.parseInt(value);
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    try{

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDirver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;user=shakir;password=shakir123");
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("delete from qesco_table where Meter_No = ?");
        pst.setInt(1,v);

        pst.executeUpdate();
      }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        pst.close();
        conn.close();
    }
%>
```

Comment: Bro: the above give me an error please help me out. this is my final project. thanks

Comment: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. This is error occur.

Comment: @user274910 You are getting HTTP Error 500 that something wrong is happening in your server side code. Please check completely there will be some exception being thrown (java.lang.NullPointerException I doubt) or something else. Give me that stacktrace of exception then I will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a record from data base using JDBC you need to use `executeUpdate("your query")` method.The `executeQuery()` query is used when you want to retrieve data from data base.

Then query should be

```
DELETE FROM qesco_table 
  WHERE Meter_No ="+v+"
```

It is not  `Delete * from table`  and correct is `Delete from table`

Change to

```
st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No ="+v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{

    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDirver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;user=shakir;password=shakir123");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs =st.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No ="+v);

  }
  catch(SQLException e){
   System.out.print(e.getMessage());
 }
 finally
 { 
   rs.close();
   conn.close();
 }
```

Comment: Why are you enclosing v in single quotes? Have a look at the code again, v is int.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to avoid Scriplet instead use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net/) and Expression language that is easy to user and less error prone.

One more thing you should move this database code in a servlet and call it from JSP. If you are still interested to do it in JSP then you should use [SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html) that is designed for database access from JSP.

Sample code:

```
<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource"
    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDirver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase"
    user="shakir" password="shakir123" />

<sql:update dataSource="${dataSource}"
    sql="DELETE FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No =?">
    <sql:param value="${param.Meter_No }" />
</sql:update>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bro!! it will work for sure 101%

```
<%
String value = request.getParameter("Meter_No");
int v=Integer.parseInt(value);
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDirver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=myDatabase;user=shakir;password=shakir123");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM qesco_table WHERE Meter_No= '"+v+"'";
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
  }
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

Comment: it is also not working and give a error please help me thanks

Comment: @user274910 what kind of error is that? its working fine for me, i will post again my whole code

Comment: @user274910 try this again! copy and paste it

Comment: int v=Integer.parseInt(value); at this line it give me an error like this: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/advjava", "root", "root");

Statement stat=c.createStatement();
int del=stat.executeUpdate("Delete from Cart where U_Id="+uid);
```

Comment: The OP's question was with sqlserver, not mysql. And had a very different able name.